# Can I have an input element fill the width of a table column?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I would like an input[type=text] element to always be the same width as the table cell it is contained in. I need to ensure that the width of the table cell is not influenced by the width of the input element.

How can I do this with CSS? Will I need to use JS? If so, what would be the best way to determine when the table cell changed size?

Comment: I think you should give some comments to your answers if you want a better one, expecially because we need to understand if we are on the right way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 9):

if this does work for you:

```
td > input[type='text']
{
    width: 100%; /*this will set the width of the textbox equal to its container td*/
}
```

try this:

```
td > input[type='text']
{
    display:block; /*this will make the text box fill the horizontal space of the its container td*/
}
```

Comment: "width: 100%" works for me but "display: block" not.

Answer (score 9):

Setting CSS rules `width:100%;` and `display:block;` for the `INPUT` element should do that.

In practice, that is not enough, it seems some browsers emphasize the `INPUT`'s `size` attibute over the style. So for example, Chrome widens the element to agree with size, thus widening the table column. Setting `size=0` doesn't work, as it is defaulted to some valid value then. However, setting `size=1` attribute at the `INPUT` element achives the desired behaveour. However, this is no CSS-only solution, and the `INPUT` cannot be compressed below a certain but small width.

Answer (score 3):

Setting width of your field to 100% should work. In this case you will also want to add `box-sizing` rule to avoid the input field from over ignoring table cell paddings.

```
td.value input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See example http://jsfiddle.net/MEARG/

Answer (score 0):

What about setting style (or class) width: 100%; for input elements that are inside a table?

Something like this:

```
td input.myclass[type=text]
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS should do the trick:

```
#my_input {
    width: 100%;
}

#my_table {
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```